# What kind of order review does TD Ameritrade do on a simple and small buy limit order for a stock traded on the NASDAQ?

Tags: stocks, limit-order, order-execution, td-ameritrade

I was surprised to see that one of my simple and rather small buy limit orders for a stock traded on the NASDAQ got placed under review for 23 seconds before it got executed (small ~= 30kUSD, which represents only 0.01% of the firm's market cap).

https://www.tdameritrade.com/retail-en_us/resources/pdf/SDPS819.pdf ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616054951/https://www.tdameritrade.com/retail-en_us/resources/pdf/SDPS819.pdf), [mirror 2](https://archive.ph/IzSZO)) mentions:

> Order Review. TD Ameritrade reserves the right to review orders
> before sending them to the market to ensure they comply with the
> rules and policies of TD Ameritrade and the securities markets. The
> order review process may delay the routing of orders to exchanges,
> market makers, and electronic communication networks (ECNs).
> If it is determined that processing or executing the order poses an
> unreasonable risk to our clients or our firm, or that it could disrupt
> the market or our operations, the order will be refused or rejected.

But this is quite vague. What kind of checks must be done on a simple and small buy limit order "to ensure they comply with the rules and policies of TD Ameritrade and the securities market"?

Also I wonder whether this kind of reviews are manual or automated: 23 seconds is rather fast for manual and extremely slow for automated.

---

The buy limit order in question:

[image]

Comment: The "mirror" link to archive.today is nearly useless because it only shows a screenshot of part of the first page of the PDF file, and there is no way to retrieve the entire PDF (the "download .zip" button is broken since 2019 [[reference](https://blog.archive.today/post/623883809154383872/the-download-zip-button-has-been-giving-a-not)]).

Comment: `What kind of checks must be done...`: Are you looking for a complete list?  I doubt anyone here can provide that.

Comment: @gaefan just a sense of it

Comment: @Flux I hadn't noticed, thanks! I'll fix it.

Comment: I suggest that you ask TD Ameritrade. It is possibly the only way you can know for sure.

Comment: Did you get a response from TD Ameritrade?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that you have entered a relatively large order, and the brokerage firm has flagged your order to prevent costly fat finger errors. On 2021-06-14 (i.e. the day before you placed your order), only 3482 shares of FRONU were traded ([reference](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/fronu/historical), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kfda.png)). Your marketable limit order of 3000 shares is relatively large; it represents 85%+ of the previous day's trading volume.

I suggest that you ask TD Ameritrade. It is possibly the only way you can know for sure.

Comment: Thanks good catch I hadn't noticed it

Answer (score 1):

Given the volatility of meme stocks in the past 6 months, particularly in GameStop, brokers have gotten more defensive  with such stocks.

There's also the possibility that TD's technology is slow and when there's high volume or a system glitch, review takes longer.

The best answer would be from calling TD and asking, "What gives?"